# Excel: Check to see if a Date is in a Column of Dates

Tags: excel-formula

I need a formula in Excel to see if a cell with a date in it is in a column of dates.  The column is a list of holidays; so I'm trying to see if a date was a holiday on my list or not.

Thank you!

Comment: depending on whether your list is oriented over a single row and multiple columns or multiple rows in one column you can use the HOOLUP function or the VLOOKUP function to find the date in your list use IFERROR to determine if it is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your list would look like this.

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmuGd.png)

You may use the following formula to accomplish what you would like with the help of `IF`, `MATCH`, and `IFERROR`.

### EXCEL FOMULA

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(B2;$A$2:$A$11;0); "This is a holiday!"); "Nope, not a holiday.")
```

### REFERENCES

- [IF function](https://support.microsoft.com/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2)
- [MATCH function](https://support.microsoft.com/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)
- [IFERROR function](https://support.microsoft.com/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611)

Answer (score 1):

To check if Date in B1 is in List B10:B15

```
=IF(ISNUMBER( MATCH(B1,B10:B15,0)),"Is In List", "Is Not In List")
```

First the match function returns a number indicating the position of B1 in the list B10:B15. If its not found MATCH returns #N/A

ISNUMBER() will return TRUE if the result of MATCH is a number, so TRUE if in the list and FALSE if not.

The IF statement is your output